# How to persist Marker from Google API Android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

[Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) does not implement `Parcelable`, `Serializable` interfaces, but i need to persist it between Activity `onPause`/`onResume`, so how can i persist it? How can i get all current Markers list (can't find getMarkers() method anywhere)?

Imagine the next case: i have added `Marker` and started `AsyncTask` to perform long-running task and update view for the Marker. Task is in progress and i change orientation, activity is recreated. How can i update that Marker after Task is finished? Let's imagine i can persist id of the Marker and *Markers are saved by fragment automatically* (just imagine), then how can i find it using id after activity is recreated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that there is no way to do this now: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4650

Comment: This has finally been updated after almost _4 years_. There's now a method `Marker.setTag(Object tag)`

Answer (score 10):

You can persist `MarkerOptions` objects because they are `Parcelable` and then recreate `Marker` objects from them.

Comment: thanks for your answer i was thinking about to save Marker object or MarkerOptions object,you gave me answer.

Answer (score 4):

`Marker`s are not part of the "UI state" and hence shouldn't be saved/restored on configuration change.

On configuration change, you will simply recreate all `Marker`s using the exact same code you used to populate the `GoogleMap` the first time it has been displayed.

If you really want to persist them (which is a really bad idea from my point fo view), this is still possible by doing so manually in `onSaveInstance(Bundle outState)`

---

Edit: See ["Deep Dive Into Android State Restoration"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekN2zvFytZk)

Comment: Marker is a part of UI and it contains icon, title, snippet and visibility properties. Let's imagine that fragment was retained and after changing orientation i have to update all markers. How can i do it as i don't have any getMarkerById() method and can't persist it in order to restore it later?

Comment: after few days of playing with it i can confess that retaining fragment hurts markers as there is no way to find/persist them. **recreate fragment/activity and add markers again** seems to be the only walkaround

Comment: @4ntoine retaining fragment is also a bad idea because it leads to Activity leak

Answer (score 1):

The marker object (for Android google maps) now supports storing an arbitrary data object with a marker using `Marker.setTag()`, and retrieving the data object using `Marker.getTag()`.

This allows, for example, tracking click counts on a particular marker. Or, storing additional data which then can be displayed in a custom `InfoWindow`.

See [Marker Data.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker-data)